# Android ADK supported devices

Tags: android, adk

I read through similar questions in this forum and now I'm more confused. Can someone help me with the following questions:

1. I have a Samsung Galaxy Y, Android OS is 2.3.6 and Kernel is 2.6.35.7 Ideally, this configuration should support ADK. Is my understanding correct?
2. When I try to install the DemoKit application on the Galaxy Y, I get the error "Install Failed: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY" This effectively means my phone does not have the required Jar files (e.g. USB.jar). Is this conclusion right?
3. I used ADB and checked the directories/files on my Samsung phone and I do not see any Jar file related to USB accessory mode. The only solution available is to root the device and push these files. I do not want to do this because my customers will not be able to do this. Is there any way to add the missing libraries during installation (automatically?). Tough ask, but trying my luck here :-)
4. Do we have a list of devices that do support ADK . I saw a link to Microchip site, http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2919&param=en546070 How reliable is this list?
5. Can someone tell me if they have had success in running the DemoKit application and on what phone models (Thanks in advance for sharing this info)

-Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the list of phones that currently support ADK...along with some nice explanation...

-Even if your phone has OS 2.3.4 or OS 3.1 you still may not have ADK support (even after rooting). This is because there is a need for USB drivers that needs to be shipped by the manufacturer.

-USB driver supplied by the phone manufacturer has to be compatible to ADK.

So, don't yet root your device (else let me know if there is an exception), instead, buy one of these models:

1. Google Nexus S
2. Google Nexus One
3. Motorola Xoom
4. Acer Iconia A100
5. Acer Iconia A500
6. LG Optimus Pad
7. ASUS Eee Pad Transformer TF101
8. Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1
9. Samsung Galaxy S
10. Samsung Galaxy Ace

Answer (score 1):

I tried some phones which support ADK.

1. HTC explorer
2. Samsung NOTE
3. Samsung Galaxy SII

But I am still trying with micromax funbook P300 I didn't get success yet.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.microchip.com/forums/tm.aspx?high=&m=591785&mpage=1#596040), it looks like you still need to have specific device support, and its unclear whether your device has that support. You may just be out of luck.

Comment: I'm guessing that too..my device does not support it and Samsung product support guys are unable to provide me the model numbers that support ADK. So will wait for others to post the phone models that worked for them. Thanks